# "In respect of" / "With respect to"

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions, phrase-usage

Is there a difference in meaning between, "in respect of" and "with respect to"?

Is it grammatically correct to use, "in respect to...."?

The full context I am concerned with currently reads:

"My recommendations *in respect to* the features available are summarised below."

Comment: Did you mean _in respect to_ or _in respect of_? The question is inconsistent. (Although neither of them sounds fluent to me. Have you seen them used elsewhere?)

Comment: I'm not sure which is grammatically correct English - "my recommendations in respect to the features available...." or "my recommendations in respect of the features available...." or "my recommendations with respect to the features available..."  If all are correct, what are the subtle differences between them?

Comment: _With respect to_ is the normal phrasing. As I suggested in my earlier comment, I don't recall hearing the other phrases, and they certainly don't sound right to me. Thus my question as to whether you'd heard them used before; I'm curious why you think they might be a reasonable alternative.

Comment: I'm doing some proof-reading for a financial services provider and "in respect to", in the context I quoted in my initial question appeared.  I was always under the impression that, "in respect of..." or with respect to..." were both grammatically correct but had a subtle difference in meaning.

Comment: You may wish to check out [our sister site for English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). It’s “for people who are learning or teaching English as a foreign language”, whereas here we’re more intended “for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts”

Answer (score 18):

Both of the phrases ***In respect of*** and ***with respect to*** are standard and acceptable phrases (at least in British English), as shown by the dictionary extracts and other references below.

***In respect to*** is not standard and no doubt results from mixing the two phrases.

> **in respect of** or **with respect to something**  [[1]](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=respect&title=21st)
> with reference to, or in connection with (a particular matter, point, etc).
>
> **in respect of (or with respect to)**  [[2]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/respect?q=respect)
> as regards; with reference to: *the two groups were similar with respect to age, sex, and diagnoses*
>
> **in respect of,** in reference to; in regard to; concerning.  [[3]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+respect+of)
> **with respect to,** referring to; concerning: *with respect to your latest request.*  [[3]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+respect+of)
> reference or relation (esp in the phrases **in respect of** , **with respect to** )  [[3]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+respect+of)
>
> **in respect to** Also, **with respect to** . See **in regard to**.  [[4]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+respect+to)
> **with / in regard to,** referring to; concerning: *With regard to the new contract, we have some questions.*  [[5]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in%20regard%20to)

It will be apparent from the above definitions that the following phrases are all effectively equivalent:

> in respect of
> with respect to
> with / in regard to

In the light of earlier comments and answers suggesting that ***in respect of*** is non-standard, here are some example usages  [[6]](http://www.reference.com/example-sentences/in-respect-of):

> Example sentences for **in respect of**:
>
> *In respect of* civil rights, all citizens are equal before the law.
> Anachronisms of two kinds persist **in respect of** this phenomenon.
> Rigid *in respect of* the upper lip, he sticks to a stern routine of exercises and always dresses in formal attire for dinner.
> The region does better than the global average on one factor, government expenditure, but it is worse *in respect of* taxation.
> It is probable that a moratorium, at all events for a short period *in respect of* trade credits, will be proclaimed.
>
> Famous quotes containing ... **in respect of**
>
> There is one principal and as it were radical distinction between different minds, *in respect of* philosophy...
> If one had to worry about one's actions *in respect of* other people's ideas, one might as well be buried ...
> Any man who does not see everything in terms of self, that is to say who wants to be something *in respect of* ...

An example of ***with respect to***  [[7]](http://www.reference.com/browse/with+respect+to?):

> **The Treaty on the Final Settlement *With Respect to* Germany** (or the Two Plus Four Agreement ) was negotiated in 1990 between the Federal Republic of Germany (FRG), the German Democratic Republic (GDR), and the Four Powers which occupied Germany at the end of World War II in Europe: ...

Finally, examples using ***in respect to*** can be found  [[8]](http://www.reference.com/browse/in+respect+to), but, as noted above, the dictionaries consulted do not appear to accept it as a standard phrase.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen _in respect of_ used like that before, and I have a hard time reading it. Must be a regional use.

Answer (score 4):

I am a freelance native UK English-speaking translator, editor and proofreader. Today, I came up against "in respect of" in a suggestion put forward by a reviewer from a scientific journal to replace a phrase previously used by the Spanish authors in a paper submitted for publication. I also find "in respect of" very odd and can't recall ever having seen or heard it before, which in my book makes it low frequency usage at best, and possibly even erroneous, despite the dictionary references provided above.  Even if it did turn out to be "correct", my own subjective appraisal would still be that it is at best "clunky" , as it made me do a double-take... and I'm still not happy with it.
I would therefore avoid using it myself, and am even reluctant to let it stand in the text I'm now revising prior to resubmission to the journal.

Comment: I'd agree with this answer. The citation in the first answer refers to www.dictionary.com. The Oxford English Dictionary, on the other hand, paints a different picture. There, 'in respect of' is either a very outdated phrase or is used more along the lines of literally respecting (or obeying) something such as a speed limit or law.

Answer (score -2):

The correct usage here is "with respect to". I've never come across "in respect to...".

Note that you can also use "in regards to..." instead.

Comment: Can you please provide some authoritative reference to justify your answer, other than that you've never heard the alternative expression.

Comment: You will also note from my answer that the phrase is easily found in English dictionaries, which is why those answering questions are asked (where possible) to substantiate their answers.

Comment: @Naveed - "in regards to" is incorrect. "With/in regard to" is acceptable (note the lack of "s"). Or use "regarding" if you're not convinced.
http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/regards.html